# Tropico 4 : are garages as huge/unwieldy as they were in Tropico 3?

Tags: tropico-4

Despite doing my best with garage and traffic layout in Tropico 3, I very often hit the problem of insufficient space to place a garage in a place where it would have been useful.  The garages were very large buildings in comparison to most other buildings.  My considered opinion was that garages in Tropico 3 were just too big.

I'm now considering buying Tropico 4, but before I do, I would like to know whether garages in Tropico 4 are just as large/unwieldy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had no trouble placing my garages.  Granted, I never played Tropico 3, but I do not consider the garages in Tropico 4 to be abnormally large.

Answer (score 2):

They're pretty much the same size in Tropico 4 as they where in Tropico 3 however they seem to handle a bigger volume of traffic and traffic jams don't seem as common in Tropico 4. If I'm honest, I hate that the garages are so big too but they're not the standard gas station, it's a full garage and car park, which in reality are usually quite large.

Comment: Indeed - I did buy the game after this question and my experience pretty much matches yours.  I wish there were a way to build smaller garages (and then obviously build more of them).  The "A garage is overloaded, build another nearby" message is often quite irritating, because the answer I hiss at the screen is so frequently "Where nearby?  Which of the buildings in the city center would you like me to demolish?".